# how to send jwt token across different domain , i cant get my jwt token after deployment

Tags: jwt, token, cross-domain, mern, express-jwt

1. [this is my jwt token code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHigs.png)
2. [and this is login code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwSfO.png)

my frontend is  in  https://hsc-momento.netlify.app/
backend is in https://hsc-momento-backend.onrender.com

how to send jwt token across different domain ,  i cant get my jwt token after deployment. some time it works on firefox but in chrome and microsoft edge the token wont save, i want to send my token to https://hsc-momento.netlify.app/ ,
in localhost it works very well but after deployment i wont work

Comment: Hi, welcome, Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417).  Thank you